# cannot link bootstrap.min.css with Dynamic web app

Tags: servlets, web-applications, bootstrap-4

dears,

i've followed these steps :

1) Download Bootstrap from http://getbootstrap.com/

2)Create a dynamic web project in eclipse.

3)Make sure that this dynamic web project could be run on the server.

4)Under WebContent folder, create a bootstrap folder.

5)Import files such as following from downloaded Bootstrap
 resources into the newly created folder, “bootstrap” in step 3. css
 folder consisting of bootstrap.min.css js consisting of
 bootstrap.min.js img consisting of images  Create an index.jsp and put
 following within  tag

But my html doesn't seem to see the css, i even wrote this line as a test but nothing appears

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
  <strong>Info!</strong> Indicates a neutral informative change or action.
</div>
```

this is the whole index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href=”bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css” rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” />

<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>


</head>
<body>

<div class="alert alert-info">
  <strong>Info!</strong> Indicates a neutral informative change or action.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your whole web page.

Comment: @Ess done, i posted it

Comment: Try to change your css link href to:
`<link href="./bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: it says invalid test string, why would i need these single quotes while it's a pure html page?

Comment: Because you use wrong codified symbols. Probably cyrillic

Comment: @Ess PERFECT! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your css link declaration to

```
<link href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

It has symbols with unsupported encoding.